How many permutations of this polyomino tiling puzzle exist?
Take a 6x6 square grid. I want to arrange 8 "strips" of squares in that space such that:

There exists a strip of each size 1 (a singular square) through 8,
inclusive.
Strips cannot overlap/fill the same space.
No strip can share an edge with itself.

An example that I recognize can be rotated and reflected to the tune of 8 valid arrangements:

I think Rule 2 is clear, but I'm adding an example of a Rule 1 invalidation and Rule 3 invalidation here:


How many such valid arrangements exist, or how might I approach such a problem?
Bonus question: How might I go about "generating" valid arrangements efficiently? I have only been able to succeed slowly by hand or inefficiently by randomize-and-check.

Can you clarify  "strip"? I tend to think the implies a narrow shape, like all your examples have a width of 1. Do you allow for the "strip of 4 squares" to be a $ 2 \times 2 $ shape? What about an S-shape?

Can you display a few more examples, and also and an example which is not valid due to rule n°3. BTW,the answer will certainly not come from a math-reasoning, but a brut-force program.

This is an interesting programming puzzle too—you might ask folks to compute the number of such tilings on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.
Because none of these arrangements can exhibit any dihedral symmetry (i.e they never look the same under rotation or reflection) there number of distinct arrangements is a multiple of 8.

Yes, a "width" of 1. So no pools of 2x2 can belong to the same strip, and the 8-strip cannot form a donut. I will post more examples when I get back to the keyboard.

I can't answer your question, but you may be interested Ziggy, a puzzle I came up with that is one instance of such a set of polyominos in a 6x6 square.

I run some brute-Force ; My program is certainly not optimum, and computation will need 1 or 2 days.
Intermediate results :

How to read it : We can build $440$ different strips with length 8, and when we search how to place those strips, we have $3008$ options.
When we cross $3008$ options for strips with length 8 and $1808$ options for strips with length 7, we have $939880$ valid results.
When we cross $939880$ valid options for strips 8+7, with $224408$ valid options for strip 6+5, and $1208184$ valid options for strips 4+3+2, it is very long.
Until now, I have processed only 3% of data ; estimation for final result is around $62 000 000$ solutions.

I confirm your counts for Nb2.  You might be able to enumerate the solutions quickly by solving an exact cover problem with $3008+1808+1000+536+276+148+60+36=6872$ variables and $36+8=44$ constraints.

Although not an answer to the question as posted, the following may be useful.
In the posted valid arrangement, eight distinct “strips” arranged sequentially clockwise constitute the square$$6\times 6=36=\frac{8\cdot 9}{2}$$
Since $36$ is the first square triangular number $>1$, there will be a similar solution using $n$ distinct strips for any $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ that is also a square number.
Thus since$$\frac{49\cdot 50}{2}=1225=35^2$$ a $35\times 35$ square can be composed of forty-nine distinct strips  arranged sequentially, as below.

Since square triangular numbers are infinitely many, it might be asked of square triangular numbers generally, then, whether other arrangements can yield a square besides the one in which the $n$ strips increase regularly clockwise (or counterclockwise) by $1$ . Generally, as can be seen, $n$ strips arranged in the manner indicated do not even yield a rectangle, except for $n=3$ and $n=20$ in the figure so far, which form rectangles $2\cdot 3=6=3 \#$ and $14\cdot 15=210=7 \#$.

This is something I've explored extensively, and is what led to the example image I posted! https://achromath.substack.com/p/pell-tiles and here is the OEIS https://oeis.org/A096979
